# Get x,y along an arc with a defined starting & ending points

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

I am trying to figure out how to create an arc and then get equidistant points along it. I've brought this here from Stack Overflow b/c it's more of a math question than a programming one, however I am not a math person so if you answer please keep in mind you're speaking to a layperson.

I have a starting point:

(144,166)

I have an ending point:

(296,318)

My coordinate system starts at (0,0) on the upper left corner.

I'd like to know how to get 4 equidistant points within an arc between my starting and ending points.

[image]

So how would I get the x,y for X1, X2, X3 & X4 ?

Comment: and how is the circle defined? it passes through S, F, and?

Comment: You need something to define the radius of the arc.  Otherwise a straight line will work, which is easy to space out.

Comment: There are infinitely many circles that pass through points S and F, and therefore infinitely many answers to your question. You need to state one more piece of information to limit the circle, such as another point on the circle or its radius. Or, from your diagram, you may intend for point S to be at the "top" of the circle: that restriction would do. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

If the circle passes through
$A=(a, b)$ and $B=(c,d)$,
its center $C=(u, v)$ has to be
on the perpendicular bisector
of $AB$.

This line passes through
$D=(A+B)/2$
and,
since the slope of
$AB$ is
$m=\frac{d-b}{c-a}$,
 has slope
$-1/m = -\frac{c-a}{d-b}$.
The points on it
are of the form
$D-t(d-b, c-a)$
for real $t$.

Choose one of these,
and call it $P$.
Get the angles from
$P$ to $A$ and $P$ to $B$;
their difference is
$\angle APB$.

Now,
consider these points as complex numbers.
This allows rotation to be done
by multiplication.

Compute
$\theta = \angle APB/n$
($n=5$ in your case).

For $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$,
compute
$P+(P-A)(\cos(k\theta)+i\sin(k\theta)$,
which is the line from $P$ to $A$
rotated by
$k \theta$.
These are your points.

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier we're going to use polar coordinates and a parametric representation. In polar coordinates, circles are defined by a center $(x_0,y_0)$, a radius $r$, and an angle $\theta$.

For your circle, $x_0$ is the x-value of the point $S$, and $y_0$ is the y-value of point $F$. Radius $r$ is equal to the difference in the x-value for $F$ and the x-value for $S$.

$x_0=144$, $y_0=318$, $r=152$

Then using a [parametric representation of the circle in polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations),

$x=144+152 cos(t)$, $y=318+152sin(t)$

Here, $t$ is a parametric parameter which can take any value, but of interest it represents $2 \pi$ radians of $\theta$. When you plug $t=0$ into the two parametric equations the $x$ and $y$ results will yield the point $F$, and $t=-\pi/2$ will yield the point $S$. Now just divide $t$ five times between $-\pi/2$ and $0$ for the five segments and find the $x$ and $y$ values that give you your arc points!

$-\pi/2+5a=0$, solving for $a$, $a=\pi/10$

So we have $t_{x1}=-\pi/2+\pi/10$, $t_{x2}=-\pi/2+2\pi/10$, etc. Finally,

$X_1=(190.97,173.44)$, $X_2=(233.34,195.03)$, $X_3=(266.97,228.656)$, $X_4=(288.56,271.03)$